Calculating natural logarithm without predefined functions in C++
I'm doing an assignment problem that requires me to write a ln (natural logarithm) function, using the divide and conquer / divide et impera technique that takes a float x as its parameter and finds its natural log with a 6 decimal precision.
After searching Google for what seemed like eternity, I only found some Taylor Series solutions that are beyond the difficulty of the problem, which is supposed to be medium difficulty.
Am I missing something?
I attempted to write ln(x) as ln(x/e) +  ln(e), and it works quite fine to find the whole part of the logarithm recursively. How can I calculate it when x is smaller than e though?

You can do it with an implementation ofexp() and the Newton-Raphson method.
